# Callback when my app is disabled

Tags: android, callback, application-lifecycle

I'm building a system app. I was wondering, is there any callback or a way to know when user disable my app? couldn't find anything about this.
Hacky ways are acceptable too.

Comment: I think there is no way. Actually there should be no way since user disabled app, and it shouldn't be able to execute any more code (a callback code) after it is disabled